# Neo4j - EventListener registration

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, neo4j-ogm

I'm using `Neo4j OGM 2.1.3` with `Spring Boot 1.5.9` 
in the documentation reference of both spring data and neo4j ogm, registration of event listener is explained as the following code.

```
    class AddUuidPreSaveEventListener implements EventListener {

    void onPreSave(Event event) {
        DomainEntity entity = (DomainEntity) event.getObject():
        if (entity.getId() == null) {
            entity.setUUID(UUID.randomUUID());
        }
    }
    void onPostSave(Event event) {
    }
    void onPreDelete(Event event) {
    }
    void onPostDelete(Event event) {
    }

   EventListener eventListener = new AddUuidPreSaveEventListener();

// register it on an individual session
session.register(eventListener);

// remove it.
session.dispose(eventListener);

// register it across multiple sessions
sessionFactory.register(eventListener);

// remove it.
sessionFactory.deregister(eventListener);
```

In my code I can't find a way to get an instance of the session.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("movies.spring.data.neo4j.domain")
public class SampleMovieApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleMovieApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<SampleMovieApplication> applicationClass = SampleMovieApplication.class;
}
```

I run the project using the code snippet above.

**My question is**: how can I get an instance of the session and use it to register the event listener?.

**Edit**: my code is built using [this](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j) code example on GitHub

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is not possible to access the current session without opening it manually. But this would not match the idea of SpringData(Neo4j).

You can register the `EventListener` on the `SessionFactory` that can be accessed when injected e.g. your application configuration.

Sample:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SdnApplication {

  private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public SdnApplication(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void registerEventlistener() {
      sessionFactory.register(new EventListenerAdapter() {
        @Override public void onPreSave(Event event) {
            System.out.println("about to save sth");
        }
      });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SdnApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

Comment: I added the code related to session to my class but i'm getting an exception 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: social.spring.data.neo4j.SampleMovieApplication.<init>()`